# How to change the uibarbutton color in common

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I want to have the `uibarbutton` color change consistent across all classes instead of having it be changed in each class? What should I do in the `appdelegate`?

Here is my code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *random1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(back:)];
[random1 setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xf63d78)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = random1;
```

Comment: what happened with your code?

Comment: @Prince i got the answer from Pfitz ,thanks for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the Appearance  section in the official documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

But what you should do in this case is

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xf63d78)];`

Answer (score 4):

Use `UIAppearance` proxy for such things. In your app delegate put the following.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xf63d78)];
```